# auth0 does not require password after logout; logs back in without password

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I've been learning Auth0 for a React / React Native project. With two different apps now, including one from their site, I see the following behavior:

- clear browser cache
- login
- enter password, now logged in
- select logout
  --> now logged out
- select login
- am NOT prompted for password again, just logged in without interaction.

It seems the session has been kept alive even though I logged out. I would expect that if I manually log out of an application, I *must* re-authorize with my password on the next login attempt.

As I said I've seen this twice now, once with my own project and once with the tutorial they provide at https://auth0.com/blog/react-tutorial-building-and-securing-your-first-app/ . Doesn't make any sense to me. Am I missing something?

Thanks ~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Seamless SSO behaviour explained [here](https://auth0.com/docs/sso/current/setup#addendum-sso-configuration-for-legacy-tenants). This is now enabled by default on all tenants and it "seamlessly" logs the user in without showing any prompts if a session exists for the user in the Authorization server (Auth0 in this case). Previously you would get a prompt that said *"Last time you logged in with ..."* Clicking it would login you in without requiring a password.

If you are "Logging out" and yet you can log back in again without needing to enter credentials, the most likely explanation is that you are actually not calling the `https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/v2/logout` endpoint which logs out the user by clearing their SSO cookie in Auth0. You can confirm this endpoint is called from Network tab in your browser when you click to logout.

The Auth0 React [quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login#handle-authentication-tokens) by default does not call the logout endpoint, it only removes the tokens from browser storage. To clear the SSO cookie and logout from IdP using Auth0.js you need to call the logout function as well. Refer to the Auth0.js logout function [here](https://auth0.github.io/auth0.js/global.html#logout).

Hope that helps.